# How can I find out the vertex coordinates of a rotating cube?

Tags: java, 3d, geometry, cube, vertex

I'm currently trying to make an orientation calculator in java and I'm having a little trouble with rotation of various objects.

Let's say we have a cube with an initial position and each of its vertices are known (and also its center). Then the cube is rotated from the initial position on the ***Y axis*** with ***angley*** radians (or degrees, it doesn't matter) and on the ***X axis*** with ***anglex*** radians. To keep it simple I would leave the Z axis alone, and also, the cube has its center in the origin of the graph.

Considering the coordinates of all the vertices known and marked with ***v1*** through ***v8*** and also *anglex* and *angley* are known, can someone please tell me the expression for each vertex of the cube?

Please don't tell me about helper methods that may or may not be found in Java. Just tell me the raw expression for every point (you can integrate them in a for loop if it would save space).

If you really need an example of initial conditions consider the following cube:

```
 float vertices[]={
1, 1, -1,  //v1 - top front right
1, -1, -1, //v2 - bottom front right
-1, -1, -1,//v3 - bottom front left
-1, 1, -1, //v4 - top front left

1, 1, 1,  //v5 - top back right
1, -1, 1, //v6 - bottom back right
-1, -1, 1,//v7 - bottom back left
-1, 1, 1 //v8 - top back left
};
```

Comment: How about if we just give you a formula that will rotate *an arbitrary point*? That way you can apply it to each vertex of your cube, or any other polyhedron.

Comment: how about we _just_ tell you to get a decent computer graphics book?  Foley and van Dam is good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You rotate single point using rotation matrix.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix

so it end up using matrix multiply eqations.

```
 v' = R * v
```

Where v is point as vector in Cartesian coordinates, R is rotation matrix and v' is new point. You have to apply this multiplication for each point.

Answer (score 1):

In general it depends on the order of rotations. Rotations in general do not commute, i.e. it matters if you first rotate around axis a and then axis be or vice versa. Each rotation can be expressed in matrix form as a linear function of your vertices. The final matrix mapping the original coordinates to the rotated coordinates is the product of the individual rotations. So you could calculate the individual rotation matrices (just google "rotation matrix"), calculate their product, and then calculate the product of this matrix with each vertex, giving you the final vertices.
In general, i.e. often in computer graphics etc., to avoid the confusion arising from the order dependency of the rotations one uses quaternions to represent rotations, but that gets more involved...
Hope this helps and gives you the right directions to look in :)